# Trying to fix Docker "cgroup doesn't match target mode" with adding kernel boot parameter

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, docker

I have problem with running certain Docker images:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: 
container init caused: process_linux.go:508: 
setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: resulting devices cgroup doesn't match target mode: unknown.
```

So, after searching I found this [solution](https://my-take-on.tech/2021/05/07/fix-docker-cgroup-errors-after-systemd-248-update/)

I don't know can this solution help me to solve Docker error,
but all I need is to add a kernel boot parameter.

```
"... systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

The problem is how to do that?
I found many tutorials with boot grub edit, but I can't find which file I need to edit?

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64), with a terminal only. No GUI.
This is a VPS server and I only can use the terminal to edit.

**Can anybody help me how and where to add this kernel parameter?**

Answer (score 1):

You have Grub tagged so I assume you are using Grub. Kernel commands are usually set in the `/etc/default/grub` file.

Edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and edit the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to say this instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 quiet splash"
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the changes and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Then, run the following command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

It should be noted that adding this to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` will allow you to boot without this option using recovery mode. This way, if the argument messes things up, you'll still have the ability to boot without the kernel command.

Comment: When I use: ‚'sudo nano /etc/default/grub', I see a completely blank file.
I am not sure If I have the grub. How can I check this?

Comment: @Aleksandar That's strange. You should update the question and specify which type of VPS server you are using and maybe someone else can help here. It looks like there may be a different type of grub used here or something else. I'll leave this answer here for others who might be using grub.